# Avoid error in R boot.ci function when all values in sampled set are equal

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I have many data sets that are inputs to a function. The data is stored in a data table, and I'm calculating confidence intervals for my function output. However, there are some cases when all of the input data is the same, resulting in an error: "All values of x are equal to  100 \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals" How can I avoid this error (e.g., just set the confidence interval to an arbitrary value like 0 or NA for the case when all values are equal)? For example:

```
library(boot)
library(data.table)

problem=1

data<-data.table(column1=c(1:100),column2=c(rep(100,99),problem))
resample.number=1000
confidence=0.95

sample.mean<-function(indata,x){mean(indata[x])}

boot_obj<-lapply(data,boot,statistic = sample.mean,R = resample.number)

boot.mean.f<-function(x,column){
    x[column][1]
}

means<-data.table(sapply(boot_obj,boot.mean.f))
bootci_obj<-lapply(boot_obj,boot.ci, conf = confidence, type = "perc")
bootci.f<-function(x,column){
    x<-x[column][4]
    x<-unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[1]),","))
    x<-sub("[:punct:].*","",x)
    x<-sub("lis.*","",x)
    x<-sub(").?","",x)
    x<-na.omit(as.numeric(x))
}

cis<-data.table(t(sapply(bootci_obj,bootci.f)))
setnames(means,"V1","stat")

cis[,V1:=NULL]
cis[,V2:=NULL]
setnames(cis,c("V3","V4"),c("lci","uci"))

return(cbind(means,cis))
```

returns:

```
stat      lci       uci
1:  50.5 44.96025  56.26797
2: 99.01 97.03000 100.00000
```

Changing

```
problem=1
```

returns:"All values of t are equal to  100 \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals" which leads to other errors.

I would like the result to be:

```
stat      lci       uci
1:  50.5 44.96025  56.26797
2: 100.0 0.0000 0.00000
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I stacked the data.table, because it's much more efficient to work with a data.table in long format. I also prefer to set the confidence limits to the same value as the mean, if all values are equal. Adjust as you like.

```
library(boot)
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(column1=1:100,column2=rep(100,100))
DT <- data.table(stack(DT))

resample.number=1000
confidence=0.95

sample.mean <- function(indata,x){mean(indata[x])}
ci.mean <- function(x, resample.number,confidence) {
  if(length(unique(x)) > 1) {
    temp <- boot.ci(boot(x,statistic = sample.mean,R = resample.number), conf = confidence, type = "perc")$percent
    list(mean=mean(x),lwr=temp[,4],upr=temp[,5])
  } else {
    list(mean=mean(x),lwr=mean(x),upr=mean(x)  
  }
}

set.seed(42)
DT[,ci.mean(values,resample.number,confidence),by=ind]

#       ind  mean       lwr       upr
#1: column1  50.5  44.92305  55.93949
#2: column2 100.0 100.00000 100.00000
```

Note that `boot.ci` just gives a warning and returns `NA` values, if all values are equal. There is no error and if you can work with NAs, there is no need for the `if` condition.